# Completion Handler::: how do you run a block of code only after the uploading has been completed into firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, closures

So... Hi.. I've been pulling my hair on this one, hope someone can help me.

it is best if I show you the code so you know what i am doing and this image to make things easier to understand.
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpUAI.png)

basically i am writing on these UITextFields and checking if they have text in them like so:

```
func fieldsAreCompleted() -> Bool {
    return (titleTextField.text != "" && priceTextField.text != "" && wasPricedTextField.text != "")
}
```

and passing the Boolean value to a my `rightBarButtonItems` titled "Done" (as you can see on the image above).

Now, as soon as I press the Done BarButton Im saving the `UUID()uuidString` as you can see here: (1 of 2)

```
private func saveItemToFirebase(completion: (() -> Void) -> Void) {

    let item = ItemModel()

    item.id = UUID().uuidString
    item.name = titleTextField.text!
    item.description = descriptionInput.text
    item.price = Double(price.text!)
    item.wasPrice = Double(wasPriced.text!)

    // This function is the one that actually does the work of saving "item" to firebase
    pushItemToFirestore(item)
}
```

and here is how my Done BarButton action: (2 of 2)

```
@objc func done() {

    if fieldsAreCompleted() && switchObj.isOn {

        saveItemToFirebase { (_) in

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Some title here", message: "Some message here", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { [weak self] (_) in

                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                //trigger this function when pressing ok
                strongSelf.saveHomeToFireBase()

                strongSelf.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            }

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel) { (_) in
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }

            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {

        print("Error all fields are required")

    }
}
```

The item gets saved into firebase, no issues there... but the completion Handler won't trigger after my item has been saved.
What I am expecting of this closure to perform is, to prompt me with a `UIAlertController` after my item has successfully being uploaded. but it won't prompt me... the code just carries on with no alert... why is my closure getting skipped?

Lastly, inside the closure I have a function to get triggered when I press "Ok" on the UIAlert:

```
var item: Item!
private func saveHomeToFireBase() {

    let home = HomeModel()
    home.itemId = item.id

    saveHomeToFirestore(home)


}
```

The ultimately goal here is to create a second folder (or a new collection) in Firebase with the item's `UUID().uuidString` as its property... hence my need for a completion hanlder: to run `saveHomeToFirestore(home)` only after the uploaded Item with its corresponded `UUID()` has been saved into firebase. and I've come to the conclusion that it is my Completion Handler that is incorrect. (I think).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the completion block in 'saveItemToFirebase' nor do you have the firebase call setup to completion so the code will stop after calling the API.

I suggest you set up the 'pushItemToFirestore' exactly like you have for 'saveItemToFirebase' except for the 'item' parameter then call 'pushItemToFirestore' like so:

```
pushItemToFirebase { (_) in
  // completion statement here
}
```

You'll basically be making two completion statements.